# MYSQL query with 3 INNER JOINs

Tags: php, mysql, join

[image: Here's an img with 3 JOINs][image: Here's an img with only 1 JOIN]I'm trying to create a book-catalogue. I have 3 basic tables - books, authors, books_authors;

books

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| book_id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| book_title | varchar(250) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

authors

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| author_id   | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| author_name | varchar(250) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

books_authors

```
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| book_id   | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| author_id | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I have a query that takes the book name and all authors for each book and displays the result:

```
$booksAndAuthors = mysqli_query($connection, 'SELECT * FROM books LEFT JOIN books_authors ON books.book_id=books_authors.book_id LEFT JOIN authors ON authors.author_id=books_authors.author_id');
```

It returns:

```
Book Name -> Author 1, Author 2
Book Name 2 -> Author 3, Author 2
```

And so on.

And I have another query that it's:

```
$booksAndAuthors = mysqli_query($connection, 'SELECT * FROM books_authors as ba 
                                                      INNER JOIN books as b ON ba.book_id=b.book_id
                                                      INNER JOIN books_authors as booaut ON booaut.book_id=ba.book_id 
                                                      INNER JOIN authors as a ON booaut.author_id=a.author_id
                                                      WHERE ba.author_id=' . $author_id);
```

When I click over an author (authors are links), the query returns all books of an author the opposite; The queries all work;

My Question is:

Could someone explain to me why I'm comparing a table with itself. Just explain for dummie like myself. I want to understand the action that is done by this query, with words or something else.

*If my question isn't properly asked! Edit me!
*Regards!

Comment: Please try adding proper tags to your questions.

Comment: What do you mean comparing a table with itself?If you are curious about JOINs loook here http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: And there seems to be a good place for an sql injection, just to mention.

Comment: That `self join` is entirely useless in that query. Just remove it. BUT because you use `select *` the number of columns returned will reduce and that might affect your subsequent code (but it might not also). `select *`should not be used in applications, if tables change it can break the application.

Comment: @Used_By_Already: The self join is anything but useless.  It expands the selection of authors returned.

Comment: @Andomar it does? oh, I see, if a book has more then one author... dang, you are right. well spotted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A book can have more than one author.  The point of the self-join is to find the other authors for the book.

```
FROM books_authors as ba 
...
INNER JOIN books_authors as booaut ON booaut.book_id=ba.book_id
...
WHERE ba.author_id=42
```

The join picks up any author who co-authored a book with author 42.

Another way to write the query:

```
FROM books_authors as ba 
...
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    books_authors ba2
        WHERE   ba2.book_id = ba.book_id
                and ba2.author_id = 42
        )
```

This says, select all rows where a matching `book_authors` entry exists for author 42.

Comment: Is the query above tested?

Comment: @noSpoon: Not tested, should work though.  Is the check on author 42 in the subquery (on ba2) as it should be?

Answer (score 0):

It seems a self join ( joining the table with itself ) is unnecessary here since you are picking the same rows.

Usually self joins are performed to join two different rows in a table. For example, if you have a table with monthly account balances for example

```
acount_id  |as_of_date | balance_amount
-----------|---------------------------
12213      |2014-01-01 | 10000
12213      |2014-02-01 | 20000
12213      |2014-03-01 | 25000
```

Let's say the table name is monthly_account_balances

Now you want to compute the difference between monthly balances

For instance, between February and January the difference is 20000 - 10000 = 10000
And between March and February the difference is 25000 - 20000 = 5000

And the output you need is

```
acount_id  |as_of_date | balance_amount|difference
-----------|-----------|---------------|-------------
12213      |2014-01-01 | 10000         | null
12213      |2014-02-01 | 20000         | 10000
12213      |2014-03-01 | 25000         | 5000
```

Here you do a self join as follows:

```
select a.*, b.balance_amount - a.balance_amount as difference
from monthly_account_balances a 
inner join monthly_account_balances b on a.account_id = b.account_id
    and a.as_of_date + interval '1 month' = b.as_of_date
```

Notice the date condition. It's comparing two different records with same id but different as_of_date. Self join is useful in such situations.

However in your case you are just joining on id and I see no point in doing that unless I am missing something

Comment: Yes. I thought the same that there's no point of this query but then @Andomar said something very simple. To get more than 1 result for each author I have to compare the table with itself.